# Does token auth make sessions unnecessary?

Tags: session, jwt, token

My question may be answered here, [Are sessions needed for python-social-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824019/are-sessions-needed-for-python-social-auth), but I feel as if I'd be making assumptions and would like to be positive regarding my understanding (NOTE: I'm not using django, I'm using mongo express react node, I'm guessing django might come with sessions built in or something).  I followed this guide https://medium.com/hyphe/token-based-authentication-in-node-6e8731bfd7f2 to add token authentication and user login to my CRUD web app, works great, users are authenticated properly, routes are protected.  However, everywhere I read about the fundamentals of session and session management states that "every web application in the world that maintains user data has to deal with sessions" (source: https://nodewebapps.com/2017/06/18/how-do-nodejs-sessions-work/).  Currently, my react client uses setInterval to regularly check if the access token will expire soon enough to receive a new one via the refresh token.  Is implementing sessions required for my app?  If so, what is it that they add that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of application.

If the resources being accessed using a token are not user specific, then sessions are not useful.

However, in a scenario where the resources are unique for different users (e.g. one has to sign in, etc), then it's wise to implement both sessions and access tokens.

Remember that tokens can also be saved within a session. Checkout 'express-session' to implement sessions in expressjs.